# Check was ExtJs model id generated or not

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to check was "id" field of model added and generated by ExtJs(6) or it actually exists at back-end?

I am using grid and json store for getting various data and generate columns for grid dynamically like this:

```
        store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
          if(success)
          {
            //console.log('Store loaded records',records,store);
            if(records.length)
            {
              var columns = _.map(records[0].data,function(value, key){
                return {text:key,dataIndex:key};
              });
              me.reconfigure(store,columns);
            }else{
              me.reconfigure(store,[{text:"no records",dataIndex:"no records"}]);
            }
          }
          else
            console.log('Store NOT loaded');
        });
```

And I do not want to display auto-generated field "id", but still need to display it, if it's 'real'.

I tried to define model property of the store with custom idProperty - but it looks like do not work in this case, 
only effect it has is disappeared text prefix "extModelxxx-" from generated id value, but it still has "id" name, not a name I specified in idProperty:

```
    {
      reference:"dataDisplay",
      xtype:"grid",
      store:{
        type:"json",
        proxy:{
          type: 'ajax',
          url: '',//will be set dynamically
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'value'
          },
        },
        model: Ext.create("Ext.data.Model",{
          //fields:["extJsAutoId"],//no effect
          idProperty:"extJsAutoId",//null,//null does not work too
        }),
      },
      columns: [],
      listeners:{ .......
```

Only way I see now is to load json by myself and then use array store.

I created fiddle for this question:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rj5

and as you see on screenshot below - "phantom" property is always false, so it cant help here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `phantom` property of the record, it means it hasn't been assigned an id by the server.

You could achieve this using a column renderer:

```
{
    text: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    renderer: function(v, meta, rec) {
        return rec.phantom ? '' : v;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried check phantom prop, but it's always false, no matter was 'id' field generated or it was received from server.

Comment: look here please:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rj5
as you see in console in both cases phantom==false

Comment: Oh, they are coming from a remote source without an id?

Comment: sometimes without id - so ExtJs generates it, and some times with id, so ExtJs just use it. I can't predict it, because user chooses this remote sources, and this sources are user content. (Imagine it as database viewer, where user may want to see some data from the table of his choice)